# Cannot call method 'add' of undefined in Rails Client Side Validations Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems, client-side

I have a devise sign_up form like this

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.text_field :name, :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Full Name' %></div>
  <div><%= f.email_field :email, :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Email address ' %></div>
  <div><%= f.password_field :password, :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Password' %></div>
  <div><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Confirm Password' %></div>

  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Next" %>

<% end %>
```

I use client side validations gems to validate on the client side. When i focus out from each of those the following errors come up in the brower's javascript console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
```

Please help me solve this..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took this long to figure the simple fix for this.

Just need to add this line to the application js

```
//= require rails.validations.simple_form
```

before that, make sure you added this `gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'` to your `Gemfile` and run a bundle install